# KnockoutJS UI not updating with rich observable array after sort

Tags: knockout.js

When I add a new teacher, it sorts the teachers and the included assistants, but the UI doesn't refresh. See the textarea control showing that after you add a new teacher, the teachers observable array sorts and sorts the asstCols in it, but the UI doesn't refresh. I've tried adding valueHasMutated() on both the self.teachers() observable array and the included asstCols(), to no avail. I don't know if what I've done is overly complicated, but the larger application has the ability to add new columns/assistants as well, and need to be able to sort them alphabetically as they're added. So, I've intentionally added assistant columns in the wrong order to demonstrate the problem with the UI column refresh. Interestingly enough, when you add Doug as a teacher, it does add him to the top of the teachers observable array, and the UI puts him at the top, so that's working, but the columns need some attention. If you click the checkbox in the second column for Doug, you can see that it updates the percentage correctly, but doesn't update the perentages for the original teachers because the UI is out of sync.

View:

```
<table>
    <tr style="color:white; background-color:grey">
    <td></td>
    <!-- ko foreach: columns -->
    <td colspan="2" data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: teachers">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: asstCols -->
        <td class="cellLeft"><input data-bind="checked: isChecked, click: $root.updatePercentage" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="cellRight" data-bind="text: accounting.toFixed(percentage(), 0) + '%'"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table class="reset">
    <tr>
    <td>Teacher:</td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;">
        <select data-bind="
        options: availableTeachers,
        optionsText: 'name',
        value: selectedTeacher">
        </select>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;"><button data-bind="click: addTeacher">Add Teacher</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<textarea style="width:620px; height:300px;" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></textarea>
```

View Model:

```
// methods
var Teacher = function (id, name, asstCols) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.asstCols = ko.observableArray(asstCols).extend({ rateLimit: 0 });  // trigger just one re-evaluation of computed observable
};

var AsstCol = function (id, asstName, isChecked, percentage) {
    this.id = id;
    this.asstName = ko.observable(asstName);
    this.isChecked = ko.observable(isChecked);
    this.percentage = ko.observable(percentage);
};

var Assistant = function (id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
};

var viewModel = function (teachers, assistants, columnList) {
    var self = this;
    self.teachers = ko.observableArray(teachers).extend({ rateLimit: 0 });
    self.columns = ko.observableArray();

    // set initial columns
    for (var index in columnList) {
    self.columns.push(columnList[index].asstName());
    };

    self.assistants = ko.observableArray(assistants).extend({ rateLimit: 0 });
    self.selectedTeacher = ko.observable("0");
    self.availableTeachers = ko.observableArray([
    new Teacher(5, "Doug", [{}]),
    new Teacher(6, "Kevin", [{}])
    ]);

    // methods
    // passes current item as the first parameter
    self.updatePercentage = function (asstCol) {
    var totalChecked = 0, percentage = 0;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teachers(), function (teacher) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.columns().length; i++) {
        if (teacher.asstCols()[i].id == asstCol.id) {
            if (teacher.asstCols()[i].isChecked()) {
            totalChecked++;
            break;
            }
        }
        }
    });

    percentage = 100 / totalChecked;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teachers(), function (teacher) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.columns().length; i++) {
        if (teacher.asstCols()[i].id == asstCol.id) {
            if (teacher.asstCols()[i].isChecked())
            teacher.asstCols()[i].percentage(percentage);
            else
            teacher.asstCols()[i].percentage(0);
        }
        }
    });

    return true;    // return default browser behavior to allow check/uncheck
    };

    // operations
    self.addTeacher = function () {
    self.teachers.push(new Teacher(ko.unwrap(self.selectedTeacher().id), ko.unwrap(self.selectedTeacher().name), undefined));

    // add each of the asst columns
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.assistants(), function (assistant) {
        self.teachers()[self.teachers().length - 1].asstCols.push(new AsstCol(assistant.id, assistant.name, false, 0));
    });
    self.teachers.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name.toLowerCase() == b.name.toLowerCase() ? 0 : (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
    });
    self.columns.sort();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teachers(), function (teacher) {
        teacher.asstCols().sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.asstName().toLowerCase() == b.asstName().toLowerCase() ? 0 : 
        (a.asstName().toLowerCase() < b.asstName().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
        });
    });

    // remove teacher from dropdown and reset the selection
    self.availableTeachers.remove(function (item) { return item.id == ko.unwrap(self.selectedTeacher().id); });
    self.selectedTeacher("0");
    };
};

var initialTeachers = [
    new Teacher(1, "Jeff", [
    new AsstCol(20, "Susie", true, 50),
    new AsstCol(21, "Bobby", true, 33)
    ]),
    new Teacher(2, "Joe", [
    new AsstCol(20, "Susie", false, 0),
    new AsstCol(21, "Bobby", true, 33)
    ]),
    new Teacher(3, "Josie", [
    new AsstCol(20, "Susie", true, 50),
    new AsstCol(21, "Bobby", true, 33)
    ])
];

var initialAssistants = [
    new Assistant(20, "Bobby"),
    new Assistant(21, "Susie")
];

var vm = new viewModel(initialTeachers, initialAssistants, initialTeachers[0].asstCols());
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

css:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 2px;
}
.reset td, th {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.cellLeft {
    border: 0;
    border-left:solid 1px black;
    border-bottom:solid 1px black;
    padding:1px 1px 1px 4px;
}
.cellRight {
    border: 0;
    border-right:solid 1px black;
    border-bottom:solid 1px black;
    padding:1px; padding:1px 4px 1px 1px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/2ymf5cyx/34/)

Comment: It looks like the Fiddle you provided isn't working properly. No teachers are in the drop-down list, and there's no check-mark for Bobby.

Comment: I see the `availableTeachers` and the UI appears to be updating correctly. I see no issue with the % updating across all teachers for a given assistant in FF, IE, nor Chrome (latest versions). Are you seeing the sync issue on an older/specific browser?

Comment: Ah, I see them now. I had a Chrome plugin blocking some scripts.

Comment: I agree, in that JSFiddle I don't see any problems with the automatic sorting of added teachers, or the percentages.

Comment: Look closer. Using Chrome myself. If you add teacher Doug, then click the checkbox under the "Susie" column, you can see in the $data dump that it updates the percentage for Doug correctly, but it's wrong for the original teachers. That is, Susie goes to 25% for Doug, but Bobby goes from 33% to 25%.

Comment: Let me clarify - Bobby goes from 33% to 25% for Jeff, Joe and Josie. It's updating the wrong asstCol because the UI is out of sync. Initially, Susie is the first column and Bobby is second, but after you add Doug, Bobby is listed first and Susie second, due to the sort. After the add/sort operation, the teachers observable array also has Bobby listed first and Susie second, but the UI still has two checkboxes checked in the first column like it was initially, but we've moved Bobby to the first column after the sort. The UI looks like Bobby has only two checkboxes checked, but diff than $data.

Comment: Got ya ... To make it easier to see I put only the relevant data in another [debug view](http://jsfiddle.net/qskfdn42/). I've had a similar issue in the past with jQuery sortable.

Comment: Yeah, nice, that does help, but you're teasing me with that similar issue comment. I hope you're going to tell me how to actually fix it! It's interesting that new teachers work but the original teacher rows are broken only after adding a teacher. Why would the new row be correct and the old ones wrong?

Comment: It looks like adding teacher.asstCols.valueHasMutated(); to the self.AddTeacher operation fixes it (inside the ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teachers(), function (teacher) { loop), but I thought I tried that!

Comment: I found the observable issue quite a bit back, but it was still not quite right. Took me minute to notice the `id` mismatch. Your comment and my answer posted nearly simultaneously. But, the `valueHasMutated` works due to you forcing the refresh. Drop the `()` from `assitCols` and you can remove that forced update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- `teacher.asstCols()` : You read the observable before performing the sort.
- Your data is mismatched. You've made a typo on the `id` property values.

  ```
  var initialAssistants = [
    new Assistant(20, "Bobby"),
    new Assistant(21, "Susie")
  ];

  new Teacher(1, "Jeff", [
   new AsstCol(20, "Susie", true, 50),
   new AsstCol(21, "Bobby", true, 33)
  ])
  ```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xhe2h9a/)

Comment: Great! To confirm, changing teacher.asstCols().sort(function(a, b) { to teacher.asstCols.sort(function(a, b) { was the issue with the sort. I didn't realize that teacher.asstCols() is a read, so dropping the parens is key. Second, in InitialAssistants I was using an ID of 20 for Bobby but in InitialTeachers, I used 21. Thanks again!

Comment: Updated jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/2ymf5cyx/36/ based on Origineil's answer.